# JS динамичное обновление PHP переменной

Tags: php, javascript

Пытаюсь реализовать обновление числа в span блоке

```
<li><a href="/activity"><?php echo $Lang['mes65']; ?> <span id="activity" class="badge pull-right bg-warning"><?=$countActivity?></span> </a></li>
```

В badge имеется переменная `<?=$countActivity?>`, подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу периодически обновлять ее?

Comment: аяксом дергать с сервера

Comment: @Sergey я не понимаю, как. Передала через роут переменную $getSettings['notifications'] , обозначила ее, как $countActivity, а дальше туплю

Comment: вам говорят, что на веб-странице должен быть js-скрипт, периодически запрашивающий с помощью ajax данные с сервера, и после их получения обновляющий их в соответствующем элементе html-разметки страницы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам нужно подучить матчасть. А именно, понять, чем на самом деле занимается php, а что происходит в браузере.

Как происходит загрузка страницы:

- Пользователь вводит адрес/нажимает на ссылку
- Браузер отправляет запрос на http-сервер
- http сервер понимает, что был запрошен php скрипт и отдаёт управление интерпретатору php.
- php выполняет скрипт, результатом является(в данном случае) html страница
- Сервер отдаёт сгенерированную страницу браузеру

Как видите, ни о каком обновлении php переменной речи быть не может - скрипт уже отработал и умер.

Если вам нужно динамически обновлять какой-то контент на странице, всё что у вас есть - javascript.
Вы можете получать данные от сервера с помощью технологии Ajax(или WebSocket) и обновлять данные в DOM.

**Например:**

создаёте отдельный скрипт, который возвращает нужное вам значение:

scripts/getUserData.php

```
<?php
  // Имитация изменений данных
  start_session();
  $_SESSION['countActivity'] = ($_SESSION['countActivity'] ?? 0) + 1;
  $count = $_SESSION['countActivity'];
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode(['countActivity' => $count]);
```

И запрашиваете его периодически с помощью ajax из javascript на странице:

```
  <div id="activityCount">0</div>
  <script>
    setInterval(() => 
      fetch('/scripts/getUserData.php')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          document.getElementById('activityCount').innerText = res.countActivity;
        }),
        5000 // Каждые 5 секунд
    );
  </script>
```