# Выполнение php в js функции через setInteval

Tags: php, javascript, html, веб-программирование

Всем привет, в общем, проблема такова:
Нужно каждую секунду прибавлять к значению `$time` единицу и выводит её. Через `sleep` для *php* не работало, поэтому запихнул скрипт для прибавления единицы в функцию *js* и выполняю её каждую секунду через `setInterval`. Но значение всегда равно 15 (`setInterval` работает, я проверил), скрипт php выполняется 1 раз, а не каждую секунду. Подскажите, в чем проблема

```
<?php $time = 14; ?>
<script>
    var d = new Date();
    var time;    
    function gtime() {
        <?php
        $time = $time + 1;
        ?>
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = "<?php echo $time; ?>";

    }
    var timerID;
    function start() {
        gtime();
        timerID = setInterval(gtime, 1000)

    }
</script>
```

Comment: На var d = new Date() можете не обращать внимания

Comment: а почему, по-вашему, **клиентский** скрипт должен увеличивать значение переменной **на сервере**?

Comment: Ну, я ведь вызываю скрипт php, он работает с сервером. А не подскажите как мне поступить иначе?

Comment: `Ну, я ведь вызываю скрипт php, он работает с сервером` - вы не понимаете как работает php ...............посмотрите как работает php в ответе тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751352/191482  ..............а как один из вариантов решения например - засунуть значение `$time` в `var time;` и на клиенте  работать уже с ним.... второй вариант в том самом ответе тоже есть. но он наверное тут лишний будет

Comment: Эм... а зачем смешивать клиент и сервер? Сервер отдает некое значение, клиент увеличивает его, а в конце отдает назад серверу, если нужно. Может вам легче все это на клиенте сразу делать?