# Варианты формирования html таблицы в цикле for

Tags: php, html

Вот таблица:

```
<table id="examples" class="display"  width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead style="background: steelblue">
<tr>
<th style="color: wheat;">Дата вылета </th>
<th style="color: wheat;">Цена, р.</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Дата вылета </th>
<th>Цена, р.</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
 </tfoot>
<tbody>

<?php 

for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo $data['data'][$i]['depart_date']  ;
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo $data['data'][$i]['value']  ;
echo"</td>"; 
echo"<td>";
echo"<a href='/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date=".$data['data'][$i]['depart_date']."&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true'>Поиск</a>";
echo"</td>"; 
echo"</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Плагин формирования сортировки (`https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html`) не хочет работать с таблице формирующийся тегами внутри php по echo. Помогите пожалуйста чтобы вывод таблицы было не внутри php а тегами html. Спасибо

Comment: Используйте `echo <<<END .... END;` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.echo.php детально тут.

Comment: @RuslanSemenov Руслан, какие-то ошибки вылезают, помогите хотя бы  часть примера с тегом и вот этой функции $data['data'][$i]['value'] приведите пожалуйста.

Comment: `Помогите пожалуйста чтобы вывод таблицы было не внутри php а тегами html` - вы видимо не понимаете как работает php .....прочитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751352/191482 ...... поймете что проблема не в том, что описываете

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Прочитал, понял что нужно разделить обращения отдельно, теги отдельно, функции внутри оформить ввиде отдельного кода php но как это сделать на практике реализовать самостоятельно не могу.

Comment: @Arcadiy нет, вы что-то не тот вывод сделали....хотя конечно стоит отделять логику и представление, но посыл был совершенно другим

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо, но я ничего получается не понял из вашей ссылки(

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Алексей Вы можете помочь?

Comment: При выводе через `echo <<<END ... ` массивы выводятся как   `$data[data][$i][value] `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваш код можно переписать таким образом. Но это не решит проблему того, что у вас что-то не работает.

```
<table id="examples" class="display"  width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead style="background: steelblue">
    <tr>
        <th style="color: wheat;">Дата вылета </th>
        <th style="color: wheat;">Цена, р.</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Дата вылета </th>
        <th>Цена, р.</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>

    <?php for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$data['data'][$i]['depart_date']?></td>
    <td><?=$data['data'][$i]['value']?></td>
    <td>
        <a href="/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date=<?=$data['data'][$i]['depart_date']?>&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true">Поиск</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endfor; ?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "order": [[ 1, "desc" ]]
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Спасибо, а почему сортировка не будет работать?

Comment: Все заработало, огромное вам человеческое спасибо

Comment: Потому что нужно подключить js скрипты и сделать инициализацию, как показано в примере указанной по вашей ссылки. Добавил это в свой ответ.

Comment: Да, я это сделал на странице, спасибо